# No se pasan los datos de una vista a otra de manera dinámica con Django

Tags: javascript, python, html5, django

Estoy haciendo un sistema de facturación en Django y en una de mis vistas es donde se pueden seleccionar los productos, se enlistan y se previsualizan la cantidad de unidades y el total de los productos. La idea es que al darle al botón de "comprar" me lleve a la vista de facturación la cual recuerde cuales fueron los productos seleccionados para su cancelación.

He intentado hacerlo de diferentes maneras, desde solicitudes Ajax hasta sesiones con Django, pero nada resulta y no consigo infromación del tema. Es mi primera vez haciendo un sistema del estilo y me seria de mucha ayuda que pudiesen ayudarme (valga la redundancia) a esclarecer mis dudas y a corregir mis errores.

Código de la vista para seleccionar y previsualizar los productos:

```
{% load static %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href=" {% static 'style/home.css' %}" />
    <title>Productos</title>
  </head>
  <body class="background">
    <div class="container-fluid" style="padding: 0; overflow-x: hidden">
      <div class="row">
        {% include 'layouts/menu.html' %}
        <div class="col-5 mx-auto text-center" style="height: auto">
          <table
            class="table table-dark table-striped col-12"
            style="opacity: 0.9"
          >
            <h1 class="bg-dark" style="margin: 0; color: white; opacity: 0.9">
              Productos
            </h1>
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <td>Código</td>
                <td>Nombre</td>
                <td>Total bs</td>
                <td>Total dolares</td>
                <td>Cantidad</td>
                <td>Acción</td>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            {% for producto in productos %}
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>{{ producto.codigo }}</td>
                <td>{{ producto.nombre }}</td>
                <td>{{ producto.total_bs }}</td>
                <td>{{ producto.total_dolares }}</td>
                <td>
                  <input
                    type="number"
                    name="cantidad"
                    min="1"
                    max="10"
                    step="1"
                    class="text-center"
                  />
                </td>
                <td>
                  <button class="btn btn-primary btn-agregar">Agregar</button>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
            {% endfor %}
          </table>
        </div>
        <div
          class="col-3 bg-dark" 
          style="height: auto; color: white;"
        >
          <div class="col-12  bg-dark" style="padding: 10px;">
            <table id="tabla-productos">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>Nombre-</th>
                  <th>Cantidad-</th>
                  <th>Precio</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody></tbody>
            </table>
            <span id="precio-total"></span>
            <button id="btn-comprar" class="btn btn-success">Comprar</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    // Crear una lista para almacenar los productos agregados
let productosAgregados = [];

// Función para actualizar la lista de productos en la página
function actualizarLista() {
  // Obtener el elemento de la tabla en la página
  let tabla = $("#tabla-productos tbody");
  // Limpiar la tabla
  tabla.html("");
  // Variable para almacenar el precio total
  let precioTotal = 0;
  // Recorrer la lista de productos agregados
  for (let producto of productosAgregados) {
    // Calcular el precio total del producto
    let precioProducto = producto.cantidad * producto.precio;
    // Agregar el precio del producto al precio total
    precioTotal += precioProducto;
    // Agregar una fila a la tabla con los datos del producto
    tabla.append(
      `<tr><td>${producto.nombre}</td><td>${producto.cantidad}</td><td>$${precioProducto}</td></tr>`
    );
  }
  // Actualizar el precio total en la página
  $("#precio-total").text(`Precio total: $${precioTotal}`);
}

$(document).ready(function () {
  // Agregar un controlador de eventos para el botón "Agregar"
  $(".btn-agregar").click(function () {
    // Obtener los datos del producto
    let fila = $(this).closest("tr");
    let codigo = fila.find("td:eq(0)").text();
    let nombre = fila.find("td:eq(1)").text();
    let precio = parseFloat(fila.find("td:eq(3)").text());
    let cantidad = parseInt(fila.find("input[name=cantidad]").val());
    // Agregar el producto a la lista de productos agregados
    productosAgregados.push({ codigo, nombre, precio, cantidad });
    // Actualizar la lista de productos en la página
    actualizarLista();
  });
});



    $("#btn-comprar").click(function () {
  // Redirigir al usuario a la vista de facturación
  window.location.href = "/facturacion/";
});



$("#btn-comprar").click(function () {
  // Obtener el token CSRF desde la cookie
  let csrftoken = jQuery("[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val();
  // Enviar una solicitud AJAX al servidor para guardar los productos seleccionados en la sesión
  $.ajax({
    url: "/guardar_productos/",
    method: "POST",
    data: { productos: JSON.stringify(productosAgregados), csrfmiddlewaretoken: csrftoken },
    success: function () {
      // Redirigir al usuario a la vista de facturación
      window.location.href = "/facturacion/";
    },
  });
});
  </script>
</html>
```

Código de la vista de facturación la cual debe "recordar" dinámicamente los productos que se habian seleccionado anteriormente:

```
{% load static %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href=" {% static 'style/home.css' %}">
    <title>Facturación</title>
</head>
<body class="background">
      <div class="container-fluid" style="padding: 0;">
    
        {% include 'layouts/menu.html' %}
        <div class="col-5 mx-auto text-center" style="height: auto">
          <table
            class="table table-dark table-striped col-12"
            style="opacity: 0.9"
          >
          <h1>Facturación</h1>
          <h2>Productos seleccionados</h2>
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Código</th>
                <th>Nombre</th>
                <th>Precio</th>
                <th>Cantidad</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              {% for producto in productos_agregados %}
                <tr>
                  <td>{{ producto.codigo }}</td>
                  <td>{{ producto.nombre }}</td>
                  <td>{{ producto.precio }}</td>
                  <td>{{ producto.cantidad }}</td>
                </tr>
              {% endfor %}
            </tbody>
        </table>
          </div>
      </div>  
    
</body>
</html>
```

Código del archivo de python "Views,py"

```
# Venta de productos
def venta_productos(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        productos = Productos.objects.all()
        return render(request, 'venta_productos.html', {
            'productos': productos
    })
    else: 
        productos_agregados = request.POST.getlist('productos_agregados')
        # Guardar la información de los productos agregados en una sesión
        request.session['productos_agregados'] = productos_agregados
        # Redirigir al usuario a la vista de facturación
        return redirect('facturacion')
    
# Facturación    
def facturacion(request):
    productos_agregados = request.session.get('productos_agregados', [])
    # Renderizar la plantilla con la información de los productos agregados
    return render(request, 'facturacion.html', {'productos_agregados': productos_agregados})
```